# symfony custom form field type error when adding child field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an entity `Nace` that holds hierarchical data. It is mapped as a many-to one association to an entity `Organisation`.

```
class Organisation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pftp\UserBundle\Entity\Nace")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nace_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $nace;
}
```

The following form renders the nace property as a drop-down with all records in Nace as expected (showing my starting point).

```
class OrganisationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('nace')
        ;
     }
}
```

As Nace contains several hundreds of records, I want to implement a custom FieldType

- which adds a second entity choice field with higher level options from the same table (categories)
- which populates the main choice field via ajax when the user selects a category

When I add the `naceCategory` child field and try to render the form, I get the an error related to data mapping.
In order to figure the data flow, I added a ModelTransformer but the methods `transform` and `reverseTransform` are never called. Here is my code:

**Template**

```
{% block nace_widget %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.naceCategory) }}
{% endblock %}
```

**NaceType**

```
class NaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'compound'      => true,
            'mapped'        => true,
            'required'      => true,
            'class'         => 'Pftp\UserBundle\Entity\Nace',
            'query_builder' => function(NaceRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('node')->where('1=0');
            },
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add($builder->create('naceCategory', 'entity', array(
                'mapped'        => false,
                'required'      => false,
                'class'         => 'Pftp\UserBundle\Entity\Nace',
                'query_builder' => function(NaceRepository $er) {
                    return $er->getCategoriesQueryBuilder();
                }
            )))
            ->addModelTransformer(new NaceTransformer())
        ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'nace';
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string" given 

at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms ('', object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
in W:\Symfony2\Sources\pftpprod\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 385  +
at Form ->setData (null)
in W:\Symfony2\Sources\pftpprod\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper.php at line 57  +
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToF...
```

### Analogy

Let me try and give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve as this Nace thing is pretty unknown.
Basically, I need 2 cascading drop-downs. Imagine you have a list of all the cities of the world in one table and you want the user to choose only 1. As the list is too long, you would want the user to first choose a country from another drop-down (not mapped with your target entity), which should populate your city drop-down with a limited list of cities.

Well, in my case `nace` corresponds to the city drop-down (initially empty), and `naceCategory` corresponds to the country drop-down (always populated with the repo method `getCategoriesQueryBuilder()`). The only difference to the city/country exmaple is, that both drop-downs are hydrated from the same table/entity (`Nace`), just with values from different hierachy levels.

Does anybody know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Is the nace category another table or a column in the nace table itself?

Comment: @SenseException naceCategory is an entity field on the same table/entity. Via the query_builder option, repository methods filter out higher level records for the naceCategory child field and leaf records for the nace field. Not sure if I'm making myself clear.

Comment: Maybe naceCategory should get an own entity so you can use the EntityType in NaceType for the category. Or is there a reason for not creating an own entity?

Comment: It has to be one entity. It is all the same data in a Tree structure (@Gedmo\Tree).